# autoFocus on to a JQuery .append function

Tags: jquery

I have this...

```
$('#orderFormDiv_Lines').append(TheOrderLine);
```

That `.appends` `'TheOrderLine'` `var` string at the end of a function. In that string there is a text box that I want to automatically set focus to called `ProductName`

```
var TheOrderLine = ('<table class="orderLine formFont"><tr><td><div class="OrderLineBoxTOP">PROD:<input class="ProductName" type="text" size="75">|Discount:<input class="Discount" type="text" size="3">|QTY:<input class="qty addLine" type="text" size="6"></table>');
```

What would the best way for this. Also it needs to go to the next table as its a .live function with a bunch of orderline classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use HTML5s `autofocus` attribute. It works like this:

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
```

If you want IE6+ support you will need to use JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$('.ProductName').focus();
```